# How to parse Json data in php?

Tags: php, ajax, json, wordpress, parsing

```
[{"name":"se","value":"test1"},{"name":"model","value":"test2"},{"name":"filter_preference","value":"test3"},{"name":"seved","value":"test4"}]
```

I have json, and I would like to parse it, and to get for "segment" => "test1"
and so on.

i have done this

```
$json2= json_encode($loadFilter);
    $json2 = json_decode($json2, true);

    foreach ($json2->$key as $value)
    {
        echo $key ."=>".$value;
    }
```

always getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach() !!!

I am doing it WP ajax callback.

Answer (score 3):

Your foreach syntax is wrong to access the $key.

```
foreach ($json2 as $key => $value) {
    echo $key ."=>".$value;
}
```

Edit from your comments:

You didn't give the "real" format in your question, your array is contained in 'filter_preference', so you have to iterate over $json2['filter_preference'].

```
foreach ($json2['filter_preference'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key ."=>".$value;
}
```

Comment: Thx for replying, I have tried, and i get for key filterpreference which is the name of column, and the rest is the value, buthow can i get to the "segment" - "test1" ?!

Comment: @user3042036 Can you add a `var_dump` of the $loadFilter variable please ?

Comment: i get                                                              object(stdClass)#7188 (1) {
  ["filter_preference"]=>
  string(378) ""[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"segment\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"Test1\\\"},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"model\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"\\\"},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"filter_preference\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"Test2\\\"}]""
}

Comment: @user3042036 Edited my answer, should fit your input now.

Comment: thanks, for replying so fast, now i get "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" I apologize for not giving real format.

Comment: @user3042036 Well, I'm a bit lost because you encode something that is already in JSON. Can you just `var_dump($json2)` before the foreach ? Then just find the path to 'filter_preference'

Comment: now I get   array(1) {
  ["filter_preference"]=>
  string(678) ""[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"segment\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"Test1\\\"},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"model\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"Test2\\\"}}]""
}

Comment: I have solved it, the json that I was getting / saving into database was not valid, i had to use also $json = stripslashes($json2); and everything works fine. Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 1):

you need to map key value for sub array.
try this:

```
   foreach ($json2 as $key=>$value)
        {
            echo $key ."=>".$value;
        }
```

Comment: Thx for replying, I have tried, and i get for key filterpreference which is the name of column, and the rest is the value, but how can i get to the "segment" - "test1" ?!

Answer (score 0):

One odd suggestion here:

If you want to use array for this then you can convert object to array using following code:

```
function objectToArray($d) {
        if (is_object($d)) {
            // Gets the properties of the given object
            // with get_object_vars function
            $d = get_object_vars($d);
        }

        if (is_array($d)) {
            /*
            * Return array converted to object
            * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
            * for recursive call
            */
            return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
        }
        else {
            // Return array
            return $d;
        }
    }

$array_new = objectToArray($json2);
```

http://wonderphp.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/convert-object-to-array-and-vice-versa/